# mobile cannot import HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used to want to import HTML pages  in one HTML.

Finally, I work it! chrome, firefox, opera is ok to import it on the desktop.

> First way

**But safari get problems also, it cannot work on mobile, all the browser cannot load this.**

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>    
<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#1").load("section/1.html");
      $("#2").load("section/2.html"); 
      $("#3").load("section/3.html"); 
      $("#4").load("section/4.html");  
    });
</script> 

<section><div id="1"></div></script>
<section><div id="2"></div></script>
<section><div id="3"></div></script>
<section><div id="4"></div></script>
```

> ---------- Second way

By angular.min.js
This one can work for Chrome on mobile and desktop, but Safari cannot.
It got the error to load the first section, don't know why...

```
<div ng-app="">
<section ng-include="'1.html'" data-0="transform: translateX(300px);" data-300="transform: translateY(0px)></section>
<section ng-include="'2.html'"></section>
<section ng-include="'3.html'"></section>
<section ng-include="'4.html'"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: What are error messages you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244387/building-a-single-page-compatible-for-mobile-where-to-start this might help you out.

Comment: there is no error message but only safari and all mobile cannot load html pages

Comment: it's because your closing tags are script closing tags not section closing tags - fix your html

Comment: thanks Pete, I fix skrollor, but for mobile only use second way can load, but it got problem when load first seciton

Comment: Finally, I fix it, but still got some bug, I re-edit it into my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Anyway way By angular.min.js this one works
<div ng-app="">
    <section ng-include="'1.html'" data-0="transform: translateX(300px);" data-300="transform: translateY(0px)></section>
    <section ng-include="'2.html'"></section>
    <section ng-include="'3.html'"></section>
    <section ng-include="'4.html'"></section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the old days (HTML4), the 'id' attribute needed to start with a letter. That restriction was lifted in HTML5.

Perhaps there is a compatibility problem with Safari mobile.

Change your 'id' attributes to start with a letter, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your script can be executed before targeted html tags are loaded. Add the whole loading thing into document.ready() callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#1").load("section/1.html");
   $("#2").load("section/2.html"); 
   $("#3").load("section/3.html"); 
   $("#4").load("section/4.html"); 
});
```

Also in your example you have a mess with html opening/closing tags

Comment: `$(function() {});` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){});`